# Pandas: Efficient vectorization of a dense table into a sparse form

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a dense table into its sparse form. The code is not efficient and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this in pandas/numpy.

Imports required:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import functools
>>> import collections
```

Input Data:

```
>>> df_dict = [ {'A': 'a', 'N':1, 'value':11}, {'A': 'b', 'N':4, 'value':12} , {'A': 'c', 'N':3, 'value':13} , {'A': 'd', 'N':2, 'value':14} , {'A': 'a', 'N':3, 'value':15} , {'A': 'b', 'N':5, 'value':16}  , {'A': 'c', 'N':1, 'value':17} ]   
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
>>> df
   A  N  value
0  a  1     11
1  b  4     12
2  c  3     13
3  d  2     14
4  a  3     15
5  b  5     16
6  c  1     17
```

A and N represent the 2 axis for which we are going to build a new sparse table of AxN. This new table will be keyed by 'A' with the values representing a numpy array such that this table when indexed by A and N returns either a value if one exists or NaN otherwise.

Axis:

```
>>> all_As = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> all_Ns = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Note: the values in N are arbitrary orderable objects not necessarily indexes into any array.

Best I have so far:

```
>>> dct = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(lambda: float("nan")))
>>> for _, row in df.iterrows():
...   dct[row['A']][row['N']] = row['value']
>> output_sparse_table = collections.defaultdict(functools.partial(np.zeros, shape=(len(all_Ns)), dtype="float32"))
>>> for a in all_As:
...   for n in all_Ns:
...     output_sparse_table[a][n] = dct[a][n]
```

This requires 2 passes, once over the dataframe to construct the queryable dct and second over each element in the AxN matrix. Is there a way this can be done more efficiently (maybe using vectorization)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to @mikksu's solution, using `pivot_table` and `reindex` for a bit more flexibility:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='N', values='value')\
       .reindex(index=all_As, columns=all_Ns)
```

Output:

```
N   0     1     2     3     4     5
A                                  
a NaN  11.0   NaN  15.0   NaN   NaN
b NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  12.0  16.0
c NaN  17.0   NaN  13.0   NaN   NaN
d NaN   NaN  14.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
e NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Your solution shoud be accepted answer. It can handle missing data in every row and column. The indices could be constructed on the fly, like `.reindex(index=list('abcdefg'), columns=range(7))`. And you could `mean` or `sum` the values if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) does what you want. With your example we have to add data for the cases `e` and `0`. We can do this in one new row.

```
new_df = pd.pivot(
        df.append({'A':'e', 'N':0, 'value':np.nan},
            ignore_index=True),
        index='A',
        columns='N').apply(np.array, axis=1)
new_df
```

Output

```
a    [nan, 11.0, nan, 15.0, nan, nan]
b    [nan, nan, nan, nan, 12.0, 16.0]
c    [nan, 17.0, nan, 13.0, nan, nan]
d     [nan, nan, 14.0, nan, nan, nan]
e      [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

---

Faster, slightly different approach. Leaving out `.apply(np.array, axis=1)` will be much faster for large dataframes. And you can access the resulting dataframe nearly identical.

```
new_df = pd.pivot(
        df.append({'A':'e', 'N':0, 'value':np.nan},
            ignore_index=True),
        index='A',
        columns='N')
new_df
```

Output

```
N     0     1     2     3     4     5
A                                    
a   NaN  11.0   NaN  15.0   NaN   NaN
b   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  12.0  16.0
c   NaN  17.0   NaN  13.0   NaN   NaN
d   NaN   NaN  14.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
e   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

You can access every row as a numpy array with

```
new_df.loc['a'].values
```

Output

```
array([nan, 11., nan, 15., nan, nan])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. Could you please also describe how to handle the additional 'e' on the A axis?

Comment: Its the same. You need one row for every desired column or row. I updated my answer, I overlooked the second missing case before.